# Session data not set on page2

Tags: php, session

I have created this class for handling sessions:

```
# app/src/sessionHandler.php

<?php
    namespace src;

    class sessionHandler
    {
        protected $_session;

        public function __construct()
        {
            session_start();
            $this->_session = $_SESSION;
        }

        public function getSession()
        {
            return $this->_session;
        }

        public function getSessionVar($key)
        {
            return $this->_session[$key];
        }

        public function setSessionVar($key, $value)
        {
            try {
                $this->_session[$key] = $value;
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/app/src/errHandler.php';

                $errHandler = new errHandler(5, $e->getMessage());
                $errHandler->logErr();
            }
        }

        public function unsetSessionVar($key)
        {
            unset($this->_session[$key]);
        }

        public function destroySession()
        {
            session_destroy();
        }
    }
```

I have page1.php where this works:

```
# app/build/page1.php

<?php
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/conf/env.php';
    require_once DOC_ROOT. '/conf/loader/class.php';

    $varHandler = new \src\varHandler;

    $sessionHandler = new \src\sessionHandler;
    $sessionHandler->setSessionVar('foo', 'bar');

    $foo = $sessionHandler->getSessionVar('foo');
    $varHandler->dumpVarR($foo);
```

this outputs:

> dumping: foo
>   bar

as expected. On page2.php I try the same (without the set):

```
# app/src/build/page2.php

<?php
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/conf/env.php';
    require_once DOC_ROOT. '/conf/loader/class.php';

    $sessionHandler = new \src\sessionHandler;

    $session = $sessionHandler->getSession();
    $foo = $sessionHandler->getSessionVar('foo');

    $varHandler = new \src\varHandler;

    $varHandler->dumpVarR($foo);
    $varHandler->dumpVarR($session);
```

which outputs:

> Notice: Undefined index: foo in /var/www/foundations/app/src/sessionHandler.php on line 21
>
> Dumping: foo
>
> Dumping: _GET 
>   Array 
>   ( 
>   )

I don't understand why it's going wrong - can't be `/var/lib/php/session` permissions error, as page1.php sets the session values fine. Page2 doesn't seem to be able to link to the same session. Doing this:

```
$sessionHandler->setSessionVar('foo2', 'bar2');
$foo2 = $sessionHandler->getSessionVar('foo2');

$varHandler->dumpVarR($foo2);
```

works on page2 and I can see bar2 set to foo2. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to do with my class, this line in particular:

```
$this->_session = $_SESSION;
```

If I understand it right, what it did in `__construct` was not what I expected to happen. Each time it would init the session, it would redeclare `$this->_session` as a new `$_SESSION` - overriding the data on each page.

I fixed by changing my class to:

```
<?php
    namespace src;

    class sessionHandler
    {
        protected $_sessionId;

        public function __construct()
        {
            if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
                $this->init();
            }
        }

        public function init()
        {
            session_start();
            $this->_sessionId = session_id();
        }

        public function getSessionVar($key)
        {
            return (isset($_SESSION[$key]) ? $_SESSION[$key] : 'no data found in session for key: '. $key);
        }

        public function setSessionVar($key, $value)
        {
            try {
                $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/app/src/errHandler.php';

                $errHandler = new errHandler(5, $e->getMessage());
                $errHandler->logErr();
            }
        }

        public function unsetSessionVar($key)
        {
            if (isset($_SESSION[$key])) {
                unset($_SESSION[$key]);
            } else {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        public function destroySession()
        {
            try {
                session_destroy();
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/app/src/errHandler.php';

                $errHandler = new errHandler(5, $e->getMessage());
                $errHandler->logErr();
            }
        }
    }
```

so it uses the already existing `$_SESSION` data. Now page2 can see whatever was declared on page1.